# What prayers to use for vespers before an 'Angelic Feast' when the feast is raised to a solemnity?

Tags: catholicism, angels, liturgy-of-the-hours

Assuming Ken Graham's answer is more correct than Andrew Leach's on this question:

[If your the cathedral parish of your diocese has burned down, is the feast day of the patron saint still a solemnity?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/79346/if-your-the-cathedral-parish-of-your-diocese-has-burned-down-is-the-feast-day-o)

And tomorrow is officially a solemnity in the Diocese of Madison, does that change vespers on the eve to Evening Prayer I like on a regular solemnity? I'd imagine the simplest thing would be to just double up the Evening Prayer for the 29th; there's no "Common of Incorporeal Beings" so I wouldn't know what to fall back on.